# convert nested AngularJS service to Angular Observable service

Tags: angularjs, angular, rxjs, migration, observable

I have some AngularJS(pre 1.5) services using nested calls in a project that we are rebuilding in Angular(11).
The services use nested calls but I have no idea how to rebuild them using RXJS.

Any help, or detailed links to understand how I can get the result I need would be great.
I have not been able to find anything sofar that helps me understand how to resolve this.

This is the original service:

```
function getBalanceGroups() {
            return $http.get(url.format("/accounts/{{accountId}}/balance-groups", $stateParams))
                .then(function (response) {
                    _.each(response.data, function (item) {
                        getBalanceViews(item.accountBalanceGroupId)
                            .then(function (balanceViewData) {
                                item.balanceViews = _.sortBy(balanceViewData, function (view) {
                                    return (view.balanceViewId === item.totalIndebtednessViewId) ? 0 : 1;
                                });
                                _.each(item.balanceViews, function (view) {
                                    getBalanceSegments(view.accountBalanceViewId)
                                        .then(function (balanceSegmentData) {
                                            view.balanceSegments = balanceSegmentData;
                                            view.totalBalance = 0;
                                            view.totalBalance = _.sumBy(view.balanceSegments, "balance");
                                        });
                                });
                            });
                    });
                    response.data = _.sortBy(response.data, function (item) {
                        return (item.isActive && item.isPrimary) ? 0 : 1;
                    });
                    return new LinkedList(response.data);
                }, function (error) {
                    $log.error('Unable to return balance group for the balanceChiclet');
                });
        }
```

This is what I have so far:  (not working - it is returning the final api data response,  I need to use the data to use the data to modify the previous response and return the modified data. No idea how )

```
getBalanceGroups(accountId: number | string): Observable<any> {
    let balGroupsUrl = `/accounts/${accountId}/balance-groups`;
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}${balGroupsUrl}`).pipe(
      mergeMap( (groups: any) => groups),
      flatMap((group:any) => {
        group.balanceViews = [];
        
        return this.getBalanceViews( group.accountBalanceGroupId, group )

      }),
      mergeMap( (views: any) => views),
      flatMap((views: any) => {
        return this.getBalanceSegments( views.accountBalanceViewId )
      }),

      catchError((err) => of(err) ),

      tap( groups => console.log('groups: 3:', groups) ),
    )

  }

private getBalanceViews(accountBalanceGroupId: number | string, group): Observable<any> {
    let balViewsUrl = `/balance-groups/${accountBalanceGroupId}/balance-views`;
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}${balViewsUrl}`);
  }

  private getBalanceSegments(accountBalanceViewId: number | string): Observable<any> {
    let balSegUrl = `/balance-views/${accountBalanceViewId}/balance-segments`;
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}${balSegUrl}`);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Instead of the `mergeMap` + `flatMap` (they are synonymous BTW), you could use `forkJoin` to trigger multiple requests in parallel.
2. You might have to use multiple nested `forkJoin` given the nature of the request.
3. While I've converted the loadash `sumBy` using `Array#reduce`, I've left the `sort` incomplete for you to do it.

Try the following

```js
getBalanceGroups(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(`/accounts/${accountId}/balance-groups`, { params: stateParams }).pipe(
    switchMap((response: any) =>
      forkJoin(
        response.data.map((item: any) => 
          getBalanceViews(item.accountBalanceGroupId, item).pipe(
            map((balanceViewData: any) => ({
              ...item,
              balanceViews: balanceViewData.sort()            // <-- incomplete
            })),
            switchMap((item: any) => 
              forkJoin(
                item.balanceViews.map((view: any) =>
                  getBalanceSegments(view.accountBalanceGroupId).pipe(
                    map((balanceSegmentData: any) => ({
                      ...item,
                      balanceSegments: balanceSegmentData,
                      totalBalance: view.balanceSegments.reduce((acc, curr) => acc += curr['balance'], 0)
                    }))
                  )
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    ),
    map((response: any) => ({
      ...response,
      response.data: response.data.sort()                      // <-- incomplete
    })),
    catchError((error: any) => {
      console.error('Unable to return balance group for the balanceChiclet');
      return of(error);
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain this. This really helps explain the RXJS process. I will try this approach and if it works for me this will give me a much better understanding of how to refactor future services. There are hundreds more much like this that I need to update.  It's easy to follow the rxjs simple tutorials posted everywhere, but not so easy to apply it to real app angularJs refactors.  Thanks again.

Comment: Confirmed. This answer helped solve the issue I was having.  I had to change a few bits to fit my real models but this definitely helped.  Now time to move onto the next problem!

Comment: I agree adapting RxJS operators for a real world problem would be quite time consuming in the beginning. But it gets easier. You could split the operators to tiny blocks and mess around with it with mock data to get a grip on the behavior. I'd say Stackblitz comes in very handy for quick small sessions.